# How do I get back to nano after hitting Ctrl-Z if I have no shell prompt (in Matlab session)

Tags: command-line, screen, matlab, nano

I'm using nano inside a MATLAB session that is running inside a screen (-x) terminal.  I accidentally hit Ctrl-Z and it immediately leaves nano, prints "Use "fg" to return to nano", but does not show a command prompt.  Whatever I type appears on the screen but nothing responds.  If I hit Ctrl-Z, ^Z just prints to the screen.  Any ideas?  Using 12.04.

Comment: You should have a prompt after hitting ctrl-z. I have... it seems that this is not happening in your case. How exactly do you run `nano` in the terminal?

Comment: I just realized I'm not really using 12.04.  I am in fact running `nano` from inside a MATLAB session, which is (obviously) the problem (sorry about neglecting to mention that; I'd forgotten I was in MATLAB).
Calling `jobs` in another screen does not list any jobs to pull up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the comments the author says that he or she is running the `nano` command from Matlab, and that there is no prompt whatsoever after suspending it with CTRL-Z. This is probably a bug in Matlab(1) which should not allow a CTRL-Z arrive to nano if it can't cope with it...

The problem is that the shell command `fg` (and `bg`, and `jobs`) works only with direct children of the shell.  But you can continue a stopped process from another shell, although this will not guarantee that the status of the screen is correctly managed:

1. in another terminal window, find the `nano` process:

   ```
   % ps ugx | grep nano
   romano   10600  0.0  0.0  20784  1628 pts/11   T    16:52   0:00 nano prova
   romano   10653  0.0  0.0  18256   900 pts/11   S+   16:53   0:00 grep nano
   ```
2. Notice that it is stopped (state `T`)
3. Continue it with

   ```
   kill -CONT 10600
   ```

...and hope it works (can mess up the terminal greatly). You can also trying a

```
killall -CONT nano
```

that way the `CONT` signal is sent to all the "nano" processes (shouldn't be a problem though).

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) I tried with `octave`: `EDITOR=nano octave` and then `edit file` in octave. Pressing CTRL-Z messes the things up quite well... so maybe it's not Matlab but a strange interaction on who receive and manage the TSTP signal.

Comment: Awesome, that did it.  This issue had been bothering me for a while!
Logging a bug with TheMathWorks.  Thanks!

Comment: Alas, new account, no reputation to upvote (yet).

Answer (score 137):

If it's the only backgrounded process entering `%` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> should return you to nano.

That said running `fg` should work too. It's a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) that takes the last job and returns it to the fore. Even when you have more than one job, it should bounce you back to the newest one.

Comment: imo, this is the real answer, it does what the op ask's , reopen the closed (ctrl+z) Nano windows.

Comment: cool tricks here.

Comment: This help me too.

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Comment: This solution saved my day!

Comment: "The correct answer is *likely* not the accepted one." #sad-but-true

Comment: wow thank you!!! this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: the only thing that was missing in this answer for me is the mention that fg is actually a command for the commandline. As a noob in linux commandline this might be valuable information. `fg` worked perfectly for me though.

Comment: noob on nano here, do I need to add ctrl + t before %?

Comment: @GerardoJaramillo No - `fg` isn't a command you'd run *inside* nano, it's what you'd run if you pressed Ctrl+Z and slept your existing nano. If you're already in nano, I'm not sure what the problem is ;)

Answer (score 36):

List your jobs

```
jobs
```

Bring a job to the foreground

```
fg 1
```

change the "1" to the job number corresponding to nano.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30228/basic-job-control-stop-a-job-add-a-job-onto-the-stack-and-fg

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu I just use the <kbd>F12</kbd> key
... and window with terminal come back.